# Unity Javascript transform object not able to go in

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

```
var Distance;
var Target = transform;
var lookAtDistance = 25.0;
var attackRange = 15.0;
var moveSpeed = 5.0;
var Damping = 6.0;

function Update ()
{
Distance = Vector3.Distance(Target.position, transform.position);

if (Distance < lookAtDistance)
{
    lookAt();
}

if (Distance > lookAtDistance)
{
}

if (Distance < attackRange)
{
    attack ();
}
}

 function lookAt ()
{
    var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Target.position - 
transform.position);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, 
Time.deltaTime * Damping);
}

function attack ()
{
transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

I am trying to make my object go towards the player but i cant put anything in the slot where it prompts you to put the object i want it to follow
the problem i believe is at line 2 but i have tried so many things and i cant do anything to fix it
i would like to note i have another piece of code simialr to this in a different script and it works just fine.

Comment: What do you mean by 'but i cant put anything in the slot where it prompts you to put the object'?

Comment: its kinda hard to explain it if u want copy and paste the script into an object then make another object and u will see but ill try to explain it anyway the second line is a variable and the goal is to make the object follow the player object and there is a box where you specify the player object

Comment: You mean in the Inspector?

Comment: Btw. don't use Javascript in Unity as it's going to be removed soon. https://forum.unity.com/threads/is-unity-planning-to-kill-javascript-support.403408/#post-3148398

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `var Target = transform;` with `var Target:Transform;` on line 2.